# How to pass value stored in state to another screen in react native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-native

So I have created a state like :

`const [inState, setInState] = useState([<View />]);`

Then on click of some buttons, I am updating `inState`

```
const breakOutClick = () => {
    setInState([
        ...inState,
        <>
            <StatusBoxComponent
                ImageConfigIconCheckOut={true}
                status={'Break-Out'}
                time={time}
            />
        </>,
    ]);
};

const breakInClick = () => {
    setInState([
        ...inState,
        <>
            <StatusBoxComponent
                ImageConfigIconCheckOut={true}
                status={'Break-In'}
                time={time}
            />
        </>,
    ]);
};
```

I am able to display everything stored in `inState`, on this same screen in this manner:

```
<View>
    {inState}
</View>
```

But I want to pass this `inState` to another screen and display everything stored in `inState`.

For This I tried the following:

```
props.navigation.navigate(ChartScreen, {
            inState: inState,
        });
```

Then on this second screen, i.e, ChartSCreen, I did the following:

```
const ChartScreen = (props: any) => {
    const {inState} = props.route.params;
    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            {inState}
        </View>
    );
};
```

But on the second I am getting error `TypeError: cyclical structure in JSON object, js engine: hermes`.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following to prevent cyclical structure:

```
props.navigation.navigate(ChartScreen, {
        inState: {…inState}
});
```

As alternative of … you can write:

```
props.navigation.navigate(ChartScreen, {
        inState: Object.assign({}, inState)
});
```

Comment: `{…inState}` , at `...` it is giving `invalid character`

Comment: this does helps in passing data to next screen, but can you please also explain how can I display `inState`, on my screen. Because with my current method of using `<View style>{inState}</View>` is giving error: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0, 1}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: As inState is an array you should do something like 
`<View>{inState.map((is)=> <View>{is}</View>)}</View>`